# javascript change element from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two buttons using javascript.

**First** creates text and removes the link and **Second** creates link and removes the text

Can a click on the link change the text? When they are on a page at the same time it works.

Otherwise it does not.

Comment: Yes, it can, but you need to be more clear and provide a code example.

Comment: If element is on other page, how this other page is loaded? You could use some logic using persistent data client side or better pass data to 'the other page' or server to handle rendered page but it could be just a XY problem. Explain better what you are looking for...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can change the text.

Any event on most HTML elements can have their default action overridden.

Having the `onclick` `event` object you should use `event.preventDefault()` to cancel the default action.

An example:

```
document.getElementById("my-link-element").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // and here change the text ..
});
```

Comment: That's completly unrelevant to question as i understand it but i could be wrong (as often...) :)